# How to retain images folder while publishing on Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

The uploaded images are getting overridden every time when a new version of the application is deployed on to Elastic Beanstalk.

I am deploying Django application and I think I need to do something with the YAML config files but not sure about it.

My application has an Image upload feature for the client. Whenever I publish the new version of the application the old one is overwritten along with the removal of the images under the image folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be storing uploaded images to the disk volume on your Elastic Beanstalk server. That disk volume will be deleted when your server is replaced due to deployments or AWS server maintenance. Plus, how would this work if you needed to scale up your Elastic Beanstalk environment to 2 or more servers? Only one server would have the image file.

The common solution for this issue is to store the files on S3.

Comment: That is perfect. I have to setup S3 now. Thank you so much mate, Helps a lot

Comment: I tried restarting the server looks like its even then redeploying the package which removes the stored files. Is there a way i can retrieve them? This is highly escalated situation.

Comment: If you are storing the files on S3 now then it shouldn't matter if your server was restarted. If you were storing any files on the Elastic Beanstalk server then they are probably lost forever now. This is what I was trying to point out in my original answer.

Comment: I totally understand what you explained earlier. The migration work was under progress meanwhile there was some issue with the server for which I had to reboot the machine and it ended up loosing at all media files. I know very little in this area, I thought only stopping/terminating Elastic Bean Stack reallocates the memory rather than rebooting it. So you mean even reboot will also remove the data is it ?

Comment: My guess is that rebooting the server caused the Elastic Beanstalk service to flag the server as unhealthy and it replaced the server.

Comment: Ways to check log or confirm the same ?

Comment: I assume you used ssh to connect to the server and confirm the files you were looking for were no longer there?

Comment: Yes I did confirm through connecting to the server via SSH